# Can't connect with ssh on fresh ubuntu installation

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I have a remote VPS which i can only access via SSH but for some reason i always get locked out after upgrading my server.

What i do:

Fresh installation of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and logged in as root:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade

reboot
```

after that i can't connect with ssh anymore. before rebooting it works. It also work after rebooting when i dont upgrade my system. What could be the reason for that...?
This is the errormessage i get:

```
ssh -vvv myserver@<ip>
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.6, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "<ip>" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to <ip> [<ip>] port 22.
debug1: connect to address <ip> port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host <ip> port 22: Connection refused
```

And then i can't access my remote server anymore and have to reinstall ubuntu again which takes about 20mins with everything.. that really sucks and i don't understand why. I only do those 3 commands which i wrote above and then i can't use my server anymore.

Comment: Tell us what the version of openssh is on server before upgrade

Comment: Before upgrade: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
After upgrade: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.7, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016

Comment: I just checked that if i upgrade ONLY SSH from 2.1 to 2.7 after a fresh installation it still works, so that doesn't seem to be the problem.